# Round to sequencial values with a variable number of hours - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I need to solve this problem that I've been trying for a long time and nothing to achieve.

In my app, the user clicks a button that advances through a calendar day by day, but, I need to return in this method, the exact sequence of a certain value that is given in a certain number of n days and n hours.

I explain: the calendar is stopped on a day whose value is: 22 days and 3 hours (1), the user clicks to advance one day and the new value for that day is: 22 days and 10 hours (2) which are converted into hours to return a sequential integer each day ahead.

Thus, in the formula `((day * 24) + hours) / 24` we have:
`((22*24)+ 3)/24 = 22,125`(1)
`((22*24)+21)/24 = 22,416`(2)
rounding these values, we have the value for both days, it is both 22, but the value for the next day would have to be 23.

Look:
For the current day the calculated value is 22
for the next day, it is also 22, but must be 23 (sequencial value).

How do I solve this in kotlin?
Can anyone here help me?

Thanks in advance

[EDIT]
Maybe I can better explain the problem with this figure
[image: click button advance a day]

Comment: In formula (1) you have 22 days and 3 hours. In formula (2), you have 22 days and 21 hours. Why did your button only add 18 hours instead of 24 hours?

Comment: Hi @Tenfour04, its becuase the calendar does not calculate this value, this value is for the day, not for or from the calendar, the calendar only participate here for the user know what day is, the values are calculated in another method

Comment: the values must be from 1 to 24 sequentially, but must be obtained by the days and hours passed for each day, so, in my example: "this day": 22, the next day in this case is also 22, but need to be 23. it's because in the next/next day, the value also will be a variable value between 22days and n hour and 23 days and x hours

Comment: I don't understand your requirements, either.  In your other example, you add 7 hours to 22 days 3 hours, to get (rightly) 22 days 10 hours.  But you then say you need the latter to round to 23 days.  Why?  7 hours is less than half a day.  If you need it to be exactly a day later, add 24 hours, not 7.  (Subject to any time-zone issues, of course.)

Comment: Then your other method is wrong. A day is 24 hours, not 18 (or 7 as is shown in your first example).

Comment: Hi @gidds look: for each day, I have a value that is generated in a separate method that returns a number of days and hours that do not depend on the calendar day, these returned days and hours, need to be converted to a sequence of days that goes from 1 to 24 for each day of the calendar, regardless of whether that day started on the 20th or the 3rd of that calendar.

Comment: Just like I said: the user clicks the button to advance one day in the calendar, the method returns X days and N hours that are more or less sequential, I calculate how many hours it gave and convert it to integer, the result is 22, but the previous day was also 22, which is correct, but the next day must be 23 and not 22, as well, the return value for the next click can be 22 days and 22 hours or it can be 23 days and 1 hour and need precisely be 24, because the user clicked twice. was I clearer?

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't follow, even with the diagram you added.  It has many numbers, but it's not clear which ones represent day-of-month, a count of days, hour-of-day, a count of hours, or whatever else.  And you still haven't explained _why_ “the next day must be 23”.

Comment: Hi @gidds, thanks for the patience - I'll try again: the calendar is on day 1 and received from the method the value "22 days and 3 hours", which is converted to hours and rounded up the value 22 as a sequential number, which is what is being displayed in the calendar bar of the figure: "< 22 >". On the next click (day 2), the value obtained from the method is: "22 days and 10 hours" which converts me to 22 as a result, but the value of the calendar bar must be "< 23 >" and not "< 22 >" again.
Do you understand now?

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho I've re-read this many times, but I'm still missing something…  By what logic should the calendar bar show ‘23’ on the second click?  How do you get from 22 days 10 hours to 23?  And how should your program know?  For example, you could set a rule that anything over e.g. 5 hours gets rounded to the following day; or you could say that it always needs to show at least one day later than the previous value — but those are all pretty arbitrary, and I can't see that you've given any logical reason for it.

Comment: @gidds, when the calendar start, it's start in one day, so the method give for this day one value in format "XX days and NN hours" which was not to see about the day, but about the value returned for the method, so, I need to show a sequential number in the bar, this number, need to be sequential accord tho the XX days plus hours, so if the value is 15 days and 3 hours, the value for this day after rounded is 15, in the next day, the value will be 16 days and 20 hours, converted to hours, it will be 17, but, the bar need to show 16 because need to be sequencial. sorry